# How do I make sharp corners with Subdivision Surface

Tags: modeling

I got back into working with Blender recently...

I remember there used to be a function that when I dragged it, I basically was able to adjust the sharpness of corners.. I think it was applied with a hotkey... I really don't remember the name of this function.. Unless I am imagining things!

Thank you so much, if you have any suggestions for this

P.
[image: subsurface]

Comment: Creasing Edges: Shift E

Comment: That's it, thank you.